# XSS via PDF when Content-Disposition: Inline?

Tags: web-browser, xss, cookies

There are kind of two questions here:

1. Is it possible to have XSS in a PDF file when the Content-Disposition: is "inline"?
2. If it is possible, does the pdf get access to the cookies for that domain the same as if it were a normal html file?

If this is only possible with certain specific pdf file readers and/or browsers, that would be great to know.

Comment: yes its possible , i used it the to bypass the facebook linkshim and achieve XSS/open redirect in fbcdn http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf http://insert-script.blogspot.com/ <== read all his write-ups about PDFs issue above references might helps you .

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there were problems in this area with Adobe acrobat reader plugin, just google for "adobe acrobat plugin javascript attack cookie".  I'm not sure if there are similar problems with the builtin JS viewers or if they are designed to live in a separate origin so that the same origin policy denies access. I don't think you even need to explicitly specifiy the `Content-Disposition: inline`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm hopeful to get a bit more details about the nature and exposure of the issue so I'm not going to accept this answer just yet.

Comment: I wonder how [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) is doing.